# Integrate $\int \sqrt {\frac {\cos x - \cos^3 x}{1-\cos^3 x}} \,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate $$\int  \sqrt {\frac {\cos x - \cos^3 x}{1-\cos^3 x}} \,dx$$

**My Attempt:**

$$=\int \sqrt {\dfrac {\cos x (1-\cos^2 x)}{1-\cos^3 x}}\, dx$$
$$=\int \sqrt {\dfrac {\cos x \sin^2 x}{1-\cos^3 x}}\,dx$$
$$=\int \dfrac {\sqrt {\cos x}.\sin x}{\sqrt {1-\cos^3 x}}\,dx $$

Comment: Define$$u=-\cos x$$

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{\sin^2x}$ is not $\sin x$ but $|\sin x|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuing from your step.

Take $\cos x=u$ and we get $-\sin x\ dx=du$
$$=\int\dfrac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{1-u^3}}\ du$$
$$=-\int\dfrac{\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{(1)^2-(u^\frac32)^2}}\times\dfrac23\times\dfrac32 du$$
$$=-\dfrac23\int\dfrac{\dfrac32\sqrt{u}}{\sqrt{(1)^2-(u^\frac32)^2}}du$$
$$=-\dfrac23\arccos(t^\frac32)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

> $$=\int \dfrac {\sqrt {\cos x}.\sin x}{\sqrt {1-\cos^3 x}}\,\mbox{d}x$$

Now follow up with a substitution, e.g. $t=\cos x$, converting the integral to:
$$-\int \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{1-t^3}}\,\mbox{d}t$$
Can you take it from there?